# Linux grep вывод строк со словами разной длинны

Tags: linux, grep

Как вывести строки где есть слова из 6 букв но нет слов из 8 букв
с помощью утилиты grep

Я пробовал такой вариант, но это не работает:

```
cat city.txt | grep -E -v ' ([a-zA-Z]{8}) ' | grep -E ' ([a-zA-Z]{6}) '
```

Такая команда выводит:

```
Belgrade Serbia 1166763
Warsaw Poland 1748916
Paris France 2241346
```

В первой строке есть слово из 8 букв

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Символ `\b` в регулярном выражении обозначает границу слова. Он устанавливается в позиции где слева начало текста/строки или пробельный символ, справа непробельный символ. Или наоборот: слева непробельный символ, справа пробельный или конец текста/строки. Сам символ места не занимает. Каждый раз когда вы ищите слова окружая их пробелами вспоминайте про `\b`:

```
cat city.txt | grep -E -v '\b([a-zA-Z]{8})\b' | grep -E '\b([a-zA-Z]{6})\b'
```

Answer (score 2):

Так же можно воспользоваться стандартным решением `grep`:

```
-w, --word-regexp         ШАБЛОН должен подходить ко всем словам
```

```
grep -viwP '[A-Z]{8}' city.txt | grep -iwP '[A-Z]{6}'
```